# Fabric JS object alignment not working as expected

Tags: html, canvas, fabricjs

I tried to align an object within a group. When I align the first object to the left, center or right it was successful, then I tried for the second object, the first object moved by itself!

Please see the image below (GIF):
[Fabric JS Object Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Jjl.gif)

I used HTML5 Canvas, fabric JS & jQuery for the development.

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mt0ccqq2/

Here is the Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var canvas    = new fabric.Canvas("canvas", { preserveObjectStacking: true });

  // create rectangle
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 300,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ff0000'
  });

  // create circle
  var text = new fabric.Text("Align Me next", {
    left: 190,
    top: 320,
    fontSize: 20
  });

  // create text
  var text2 = new fabric.Text("Align me first", {
    left: 100,
    top: 200,
    fontSize: 20
  });

  canvas.add(rect, text, text2);
  canvas.renderAll();

// GROUP ON SELECTION
canvas.on("selection:created", function(e) {
    var activeObj = canvas.getActiveGroup();
  if(activeObj.type === "group") {
    console.log("Group created");

var groupWidth = e.target.getWidth();
var groupHeight = e.target.getHeight();


e.target.forEachObject(function(obj) {
    var itemWidth = obj.getBoundingRect().width;
  var itemHeight = obj.getBoundingRect().height;

  // ================================
        // OBJECT ALIGNMENT: " H-LEFT "
        // ================================
  $('#objAlignLeft').click(function() {
      obj.set({
        left: -(groupWidth / 2),
        originX: 'left'
      });
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  // ================================
        // OBJECT ALIGNMENT: " H-CENTER "
        // ================================
  $('#objAlignCenter').click(function() {
      obj.set({
        left: (0 - itemWidth/2),
        originX: 'left'
      });
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
  // ================================
        // OBJECT ALIGNMENT: " H-RIGHT "
        // ================================
  $('#objAlignRight').click(function() {
      obj.set({
        left: (groupWidth/2 - itemWidth/2),
        originX: 'center'
      });
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

});

 }
}); // END OF " SELECTION:CREATED "

});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not moving i tried and i align next text to move little forward first text is not moved check here https://jsfiddle.net/Venkatachalam_Perisetla/mt0ccqq2/1/

Comment: it's still moving the other object when you try to align for the second times.

Comment: can u check my jsfiddle link, otherwise please explain me what is your exact requirement.

Comment: yes, i have checked your jsfiddle but still the same with my fiddle. Please check the screenshot (GIF) here https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2Jjl.gif for the problem..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, right?

[image]

Here's the tweak to your code...

```
canvas.on("selection:cleared", function(e) {
  $('#objAlignLeft').off('click');
  $('#objAlignCenter').off('click');
  $('#objAlignRight').off('click');
});
```

And here's the all important JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/xxrqbhph/.

Let me know if you have any further questions.  Happy to help!

Comment: Got this error :(:  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getActiveGroup' of undefined`

Comment: @kabrice getActiveGroup method is removed. Use this: canvas.getActiveObjects();